# Keyboard events not working for second instance

Tags: selenium-webdriver

I am facing a strange issue with keyboard event handling. I am able to use keyboard event on my screen for the first event. However, when I try for the second event it fails to execute.
e.g. For zoom, Ctrl+1 works only for the first time. Same happens when I try using some other event after the first one.

Note: It works absolutely fine if I use mouse events for above actions.
I am using

```
Actions action = actions.sendKeys(Keys.CONTROL, Keys.NUMPAD1);
action.perform();
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know how but when i when used "send keys" command two times and "perform "once it started to work.
However, this has happened with few keyboard events. Others work with single usage of send keys.

```
Actions action = actions.sendKeys(Keys.CONTROL, Keys.NUMPAD1);
Actions action = actions.sendKeys(Keys.CONTROL, Keys.NUMPAD1);
action.perform();
```